# Why doesn't super key display some scripts?

Tags: command-line, scripts, search

I recently downloaded CrashPlan for my laptop running 12.04. It installed a shortcut to the desktop to the GUI which is pointing at `/usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanDesktop` (a shell script). This is all good and well, but I would rather remove the icon and be able to launch it by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> and searching for "crash" so that I don't have to keep the icon on my desktop. However, it doesn't show up in the results.

Why is this? And is there to make it appear in the search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get an app into the launcher. What you need to do for this is to create what is called a desktop file. Here's what you need to do.

1) Open up your favorite text editor, and copy the following into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=CrashPlan
Comment="Some description of what this does"
Icon=/path/to/some/icon.svg
Exec="/usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanDesktop"
Categories=Application;System;
Terminal=false
```

You should replace the /path/to/some/icon with the full path to whatever you want to be this things icon or you can remove that line if you don't care.

2) Save this file as `/home/[username]/.local/share/applications/crashplan.desktop`.

Now, if you did this right, CrashPlan should appear in your dash with the icon you chose.